# We are getting error as : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable what should we do

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, data-science

```
def split_data(data):
    print("Splitting data...")
    features = data[:,1]
    labels = data[:,0]
    training_data, test_data, training_labels, test_labels = train_test_split( features, 
    labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
    print(labels)
    print("flag 3: splitted data")
    return training_data, test_data, training_labels, test_labels
```

And here we are getting error as :
 in split_data(data)
1 def split_data(data):
2     print("Splitting data...")
----> 3     features = data[:,1]
4     labels = data[:,0]
5     training_data, test_data, training_labels, test_labels = train_test_split( features, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Here type of data is array, we have tried data as dataframe also but it didn't work,What should we do?

Comment: perhaps you expect data to be an array, but it seems like it is None. What you should do is check if data is None

Comment: `data` is not an array, it is `None`. You need to examine the place where you're calling this function and determine why.